# Get all the predicates that are verb and are a predicate

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming

I have in a .pl file the follow:

```
...
verb(love).
verb(think).
love(mom, dad).
noun(head).

insert(Pre):- Pre =.. [N | Param], assertz(verb(N)), assertz(Pre).
insertAll:- insert(walk(henry, park)), insert(punch(ken, henry)).
:-insertAll.

getAll(N):-verb(N), current_predicate(N/2).

...
```

I want to get all the predicates that are verb and are a predicate with arity 2

```
getAll(N).
```

**Output:**

```
Result = [love].
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly, the only problem is that you need to specify that verb is dynamic.

**Your .pl file**

```
...

:-dynamic verb/1

verb(love).
verb(think).
love(mom, dad).
noun(head).

insert(Pre):- Pre =.. [N | Param], assertz(verb(N)), assertz(Pre).
insertAll:- insert(walk(henry, park)), insert(punch(ken, henry)).
:-insertAll.

getAll(N):-verb(N), current_predicate(N/2).

...
```

**Query**

```
getAll(N).
```

**Output**

```
N = love ;
N = walk ;
N = punch.
```